# Adding symmetricds to slony slave in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, symmetricds

Can we add triggers to the slave in postgres which is using slony for replication? These additional triggers (which will not be present in master) are needed for some additional work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql allows declaration of multiple triggers on a table. They are executed in alphabetical order: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

> If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event,
>   they will be fired in alphabetical order by name.

Feel free to add the triggers.

Comment: Dear Boris, since slony is doing replication, we were concerned that it will overwrite these triggers once it replicates from the master. Please comment. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest I don't know. Give it a try on your development environment